# Show/Hide <div> clicking on an img

Tags: jquery, show-hide, togglebutton

i have an image and i'd like to show or hide a div clicking on that image. When the page is load, the div should be hidden

I used this script:

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("img.menubutton").click(function(){
    $("div.form").toggleClass("hide");
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<img class="menubutton" src="img/menuicon.png">
<div class="form">
    ....
</div>
</body>
```

It works (but the clicking-area is only the top-part of image... not all the image)... but if i enter a related rule in css:

```
img.menubutton {
position: fixed;
top: 5px;
left: 10px;
}
```

it doesn't work anymore.

Is there a way to:

- Use all the image-area for clicking
- Positioning the img where i want with css, withoud lose the script effect?

Thank you!

Comment: please set up a jsfiddle to demonstrate

Comment: I'm not seeing any issue, it's working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/hqvy3Lu7/

Comment: I tryed to set up jsfiddle but it doesn't work. This is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/4v3qzjcL/

You can see the live demo (with the problem) here: http://www.openews.it/gommista/gommeincasa.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ul` element covers your image. You can try to add `z-index` to your image.

```
img.menubutton {
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the problem of `click`. It caused by `ul` element absolute position is cover the img element. You can try click top of the img, it works.

So add css:

```
ul.topmenu {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

---

PS: There are some other problems in your jsfiddle:

1. U didn't include jquery
2. When the `a` around the `img`, it's better add click  event on `a` instead of `img`. Or u should use `e.stopPropagation();` to prevent click event bubble.

code: http://jsfiddle.net/4v3qzjcL/2/

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers have mentioned, the problem is the absolute positioning of the `ul` partially covering your clickable area.

Here is how I'd do it.

In your fiddle you have an `a` tag. Use the href in that better. Give your target `div` an id and set the href to that. This is more meaningful than an orphan `#` Then instead of using `toggleClass`, just use `toggle` to show and hide.

Also instead of using `absoute` positioning, which often causes headaches because it takes the element from the normal document flow, use `display:inline-block` for your `ul` and adjust the left padding as needed:

```js
   $(document).ready(function () {
   $("#frmLink").click(function () {
       var target = $(this).attr("href");//get the targer from the href attribute
       $(target).toggle();
       return false; 
   });
});
```

```css
#form {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 45px;
  background: yellow;
}
div#topmenu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #003399;
}
img.menubutton1 {
  top: 5px;
  left: 10px;
}
ul.topmenu {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  top: -5px;
  padding-left: 0;
}
li.topmenu {
  padding: 5px 40px;
  display: inline;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="topmenu">
  <a href="#form" id="frmLink">
    <img class="menubutton" src="http://www.openews.it/gommista/img/menuicon.png">
  </a>

  <ul class="topmenu">
    <li class="topmenu">Home</li>
    <li class="topmenu">Gomme in Casa</li>
    <li class="topmenu">Gomme in Deposito</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="form">
  <div class="insert-form">
    <form name="inserisciGommeCasa" action="inserisciGommeCasa.php" method="POST"> <b>INSERISCI NUOVE GOMME</b>
      <br>
      <label>Marca:
        <input type="text" name="marca">
      </label>
      <br>
      <label>Modello:
        <input type="text" name="modello">
      </label>
      <br>
      <label>Dimensioni:
        <input type="text" name="dimensioni">
      </label>
      <br>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="tipologia" value="invernali">Invernali</label>
      <br>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="tipologia" value="estive">Estive</label>
      <br>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="tipologia" value="miste">Miste</label>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Inserisci">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="search-form">
    <form name="cercaGommeCasa" action="gommeincasa.php" method="GET"> <b>CERCA GOMME</b>
      <br>
      <label>Marca:
        <input type="text" name="marca">
      </label>
      <br>
      <label>Modello:
        <input type="text" name="modello">
      </label>
      <br>
      <label>Dimensioni:
        <input type="text" name="dimensioni">
      </label>
      <br>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="tipologia" value="invernali">Invernali</label>
      <br>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="tipologia" value="estive">Estive</label>
      <br>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="tipologia" value="miste">Miste</label>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Cerca">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle Version](http://jsfiddle.net/4v3qzjcL/4/)

Finally, you can make this more semantic and cleaner by getting rid of the `br` tags and styling the labels a blocks. Also use `fieldsets` to separate your forms and use `legend` for the form headings.

[More Semantic Version](http://jsfiddle.net/4v3qzjcL/5/)